# i'm using passenger with apache and it cannot find my locally installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

if i use ./script/server my app runs fine but when i try to it it through passenger on apache it gives me

`Missing the Rails 2.3.5 gem.`

if i vendorize rails it seems that it finds it but then it fails for missing gems even though they are in vendor/gems.

ideally, i would not want to vendorize rails or gems for such a  reason, but would expect that it picks up gems from my default home location ~/.gems

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be a permissions error or just the fact that passenger isn't running as the user where the gems are installed. Take a look at [The user guide](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerDefaultUser) and user switching.

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921623/passenger-does-not-recognize-locally-installed-gem-works-with-packed-gems/3921972#3921972) to a similar question ["Passenger does not recognize locally installed gem, works with packed gems"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3921623/23723).