# Passenger does not recognize locally installed gem, works with packed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

This is a production server. I have Passenger installed and it works properly for the most part. However, I always have to pack the gems with the projects. If I don't, I get this error message:

```
Missing the Rails 2.3.8 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.8 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
```

gem list --local returns rails 2.3.8 as well as 2.3.5 so the gem is actually not missing. Since I could not resolve this issue, I keep including the rails gem in every project (which results is a properly working application).

Any ideas?

P.S I did try the suggestions of the error message, my config is asking for 2.3.8 which I have installed

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are installing/running the `gem` command with the same user permission as Passenger.

By default, Passenger runs inside Apache which has superuser privileges.
If you type `gem install`, the Gems will be saved in your user folder unless you are root.

Comment: I installed the gems with sudo, and rails 2.3.8 gem appear when I do gem list --local as the local user as well as root.

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing gems logged in as a normal user (non-root) or without using `sudo`, your gems go into `.gems` folder in your home directory (eg. `/home/matt/.gems`) and Passenger cannot find them.

You can either install them as root/sudo or add your local directory to your GEM_HOME/GEM_PATH. Not sure if this is the best solution, but I put this at the top of `config/environment.rb` in my application:

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
  ENV['HOME'] = "/home/matt"
  ENV['GEM_HOME'] = "/home/matt/.gems"
  ENV['GEM_PATH'] = "/home/matt/.gems"
end
```