# How do I deploy a Sinatra app with Nginx and Passenger?

Tags: rubygems, nginx, sinatra, passenger, rack

I'm on a Dreamhost virtual private server. I have never written a Sinatra app, or any other Rack app before. I'm just trying to get a Hello World app to run but I keep getting the Passenger error page with the error:

```
no such file to load -- rack
```

I have created `public/` and `tmp/` in the domain / app root.

Also in the app root is this `config.ru`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'myapp'

run Sinatra::Application
```

which I pulled from the Passenger on Nginx docs, [Sinatra section](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_sinatra).

Finally, this is `myapp.rb`, which I pulled from the top of the Sinatra [Intro doc](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html).

```
# myapp.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello world!'
end
```

How can I get this to work?

---

**EDIT**

Here are the top three lines of the stack trace given on the Passenger error page:

```
0 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb 31 in `gem_original_require'
1 /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb 31 in `require'
2 /dh/nginx/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 145 in `load_rack_app'
```

---

**UPDATE**

I suspect I have discovered *why* Passenger can't find rack, but I still haven't figured out a solution. At the top of my `nginx.conf` is this line:

```
user dhapache;
```

It would seem that Passenger is looking for the gems either as `dhapache` or as `root` and I'm not sure which it is based on the process list given from `ps aux | less`:

```
root     PassengerNginxHelperServer /dh/nginx/passenger ruby 3 4 0 6 0 300 1 nobody 999 150 /tmp/passenger.19012
root     Passenger spawn server
dhapache nginx: worker process
dhapache nginx: worker process
root     nginx: master process /dh/nginx/bin/nginx-be -c /dh/nginx/servers/httpd-ps77303/nginx.conf -p /dh/nginx/servers/httpd-ps77303/var/
```

However, in either case the gem paths listed by `gem env` point only to places where there are no gems. If Passenger is looking for gems in those places, it won't find any.

Gem paths from `sudo -u dhapache gem env`

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8
/root/.gem/ruby/1.8
```

Gem paths from `sudo -u root gem env`

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8
/dh/apache/.gem/ruby/1.8
```

In both cases, the first (identical) directory is empty and the second directory listed does not exist.

In this server setup, the applications are hosted under `/home/[username]/[domain]/` and the local gems are in `/home/[username]/.gems/`. Running `gem env` as the app user shows the local gem path.

How do I get Passenger to find my local gems?

Comment: did you solve the problem? do you have rack installed? e.g., what does `gem query -n rack` show?

Comment: still haven't figured it out. running that command produces this output: `rack (1.3.6, 1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3, 0.6.13)
rack-protection (1.2.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1, 0.5.6)`

Comment: try to check where that file is and whether it has the right permissions. something like `find /usr/lib/ruby/ -name rake.rb -exec ls -l '{}' ';'`

Comment: the permissions seem right: 644

Comment: well, as a last resort down this path, you can try to run your program with `strace` and see where ruby is looking for that file.

Comment: I'm not sure how one would use `strace` in this situation, but I've updated the question to show my findings in the spirit of your suggestion.

Comment: did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921623/passenger-does-not-recognize-locally-installed-gem-works-with-packed-gems) and [this](http://blog.phusion.nl/2008/12/16/passing-environment-variables-to-ruby-from-phusion-passenger/)?

Answer (score -1):

Use Bundler's [Gemfile](http://gembundler.com/gemfile.html). Use [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics/).

Comment: I don't disagree with that - though it's not really an answer. And I have long ago given up on this situation and moved to Rackspace where I have true root access. Thanks anyway.